# cmake cant find OpenGL.framework

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, macos-sierra

I have an openGL project built using cmake. I am running macOS 10.12. I've recently upgraded to Xcode 9, which seems to contain the macOS 10.13 SDK. when I try to build my project, I see this error:
`make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework', needed by 'main'.  Stop.`

The Xcode app bundle I have contains a similarly named directory, `MacOSX10.13.sdk`. I have tried to set both `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` (to the SDK directory present on my system) and `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` (to 10.13).

How can I instruct CMake to use either the correct SDK folder, or just use the `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework` in the macOS installation? I couldn't find any mention of the erroneous directory name, other than in the generated `Makefile`.

Comment: After upgrading libraries/frameworks, using by a project, you need to **clean the previous project's CMake cache** and then reconfigure the project. With makefiles, cleaning project's cache is performed by removing `CMakeCache.txt` from the project's build directory. I don't know how this should be done in XCode.

Comment: thank you @Tsyvarev, i did get the same issue after doing a clean build of the project and even starting a new project from scratch just to reproduce the issue